# MySQL "INSERT INTO" tag error

Tags: php, sql, database

This is my code:

```
<?php 
$dbhost = 'localhost'; 
$dbuser = 'root'; 
$dbpass = ''; 
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass); 
if(! $conn ) 
{ 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
$sql = "INSERT INTO together (`First Name`,`Last Name`, `Email id`,'Password') 
VALUES ( '$_POST[First name]', '$_POST[Last name]', '$_POST[Email_id]','$_POST[Password]')"; 

mysql_select_db('test'); 
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn ); 
if(! $retval ) 
{ 
die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo "You have successfully singed up for together \n"; 
mysql_close($conn); 
?>
```

but when I run it, I get the following error:

```
( Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting ']' in C:\wamp\www\MyProjects\Sign_up.php on line 11)
```

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: User extract($_POST); and simply call variables like this : $sql = "INSERT INTO together (`First Name`,`Last Name`, `Email id`,'Password') 
VALUES ( '$First_name', '$Last_name', '$Email_id','$Password')";

Answer (score 1):

Change the `'Password'` to `Password` in the INSERT query. Also, `$_POST[First name]` will not work - you need to call: `$_POST['First name']` (with the quotes)

Further, it's not recommended to use `mysql_*` functions - it's obsolete (see the *[red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)*) and unsafe. Use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Here's an example using PDO:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=test", $username, $password);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO together (`First Name`,`Last Name`, `Email id`,'Password') 
      VALUES (:fname, :lname, :email_id, :pwd)") ;

    /*** bind the paramaters ***/
    $stmt->bindParam(':fname', $fname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lname', $lname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email_id', $email_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pwd', $pwd, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    /*** execute the prepared statement ***/
    $stmt->execute();

    /*** fetch the results ***/
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    /*** loop of the results ***/
    foreach($result as $row)
        {
        echo $row['`First Name`'].'<br />';
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Man, you need do this in your array:

```
$_POST["Email_id"]
```

Also, the fields does not need of '`' in query sql. Just if you really created the fields with whitespace in names

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you just forgetting quotes between the `[]`?  at : `( '$_POST[First name]', '$_POST[Last name]', '$_POST[Email_id]','$_POST[Password]')`

Answer (score 0):

Variable substitution doesn't work with array values, as you've entered here. If you don't want to use concatenation, you need to wrap each array value with `{ }`, like so:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO together (`First Name`,`Last Name`, `Email id`,'Password') 
VALUES ( '{$_POST[First name]}', '{$_POST[Last name]}', '{$_POST[Email_id]}','{$_POST[Password]}')";
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

There are multiple issues with your code, though. For starters, the `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated, so you should not be using them in new code. There are alternatives already in place, namely the MySQLi and PDO libraries. You also should **never** use raw form input in a query; Google "SQL injection" to learn why. PHP has a filter library you can use to sanitize your inputs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO together (`First Name`,`Last Name`, `Email id`,`Password`) 
VALUES ( '$_POST[First name]', '{$_POST['Last name']}', '$_POST[Email_id]','$_POST[Password]')";
```

since the array key contains a space, you can't use simple interpolation, you need to put it in quotes, and that means you have to use `{...}` around the variable.

or if the actual name of the input field is `name="Last_name"` then you need to include the underscore:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO together (`First Name`,`Last Name`, `Email id`,`Password`) 
VALUES ( '$_POST[First name]', '$_POST['Last_name']', '$_POST[Email_id]','$_POST[Password]')";
```